# Entity Framework - LINQ statement with WHERE clause based on NULLABLE parameter

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a a method that return a list of languages. It has a nullable parameter of languageId. If passed, the method returns that language otherwise returns the list of languages.

I want to know if I can simplify this piece of code to have a select and where clause in one statement.

```
public List<Language> GetLanguageList(LanguageMapper ctx, int? languageId)
{

    List<Language> languages = ctx.LANGUAGELIST
                                    .Select(e => new Language()
                                    {
                                        LanguageId = e.LANGUAGEID,
                                        LanguageName = e.LANGUAGE
                                    })
                                    .ToList();                    
    if (languageId.HasValue)
    {
        languages = languages.Where(x => x.LanguageId == languageId).ToList();
    }

    return languages;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do the `.Where` before the `.Select`, like this:

```
public List<Language> GetLanguageList(LanguageMapper ctx, int? languageId)
{
    var query = ctx.LANGUAGELIST.AsQueryable();
    if (languageId.HasValue)
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.LanguageId == languageId.Value);
    }

    List<Language> languages = query.Select(e => new Language()
                                    {
                                        LanguageId = e.LANGUAGEID,
                                        LanguageName = e.LANGUAGE
                                    })
                                    .ToList();                    
    return languages;
}
```

By using `IQueryable<Language>` in this way, you ensure that only one call is made to the database, regardless of what parameters are passed to this method.

Comment: So there is not way I can have the conditional where clause with in the main query? Although I am not concerned about the performance here but still, is there any impact of filtering/querying twice?

Comment: p.s.w.g has the statement set us as an IQueryable so you are not filtering twice. You are building up the statement and deferring execution. The ToList() call at the end executes the statement once and only once.

Comment: thanks for the explanation Khepri. thanks p.s.w.g for the solution.. I see Jon Egerton has a solution to include filter with select in one linq statement. Not sure which is better though.

Comment: @kuul13 More precisely, entity framework will only execute the query against database when you create an `IEnumerator` (which is done in `ToList`). The `IQueryable` interface allows you to manipulate the query *before* it gets executed. This is the easiest way to create this kind of dynamic query.

Comment: Thanks p.s.w.g for the solution and explanation. Thanks to Jon too for giving another way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can include the `HasValue` check in the where clause:

```
public List<Language> GetLanguageList(LanguageMapper ctx, int? languageId)
{

    List<Language> languages = ctx.LANGUAGELIST
                                    .Where(e => !languageId.HasValue || e.LanguageId == languageId)
                                    .Select(e => new Language()
                                    {
                                        LanguageId = e.LANGUAGEID,
                                        LanguageName = e.LANGUAGE
                                    })
                                    .ToList();                    

    return languages;

}
```

Note: p.s.w.g's answer will lead to cleaner, more efficient sql in the instance where `languageId` is null in this particular example, but its worth seeing that this option is available for more complex examples.

Comment: shouldn't it be && instead of || (and no negation before HasValue)?

Comment: @MareInfinitus: No, either the input param is null, so we want all rows, or the input param isn't null, so we do the match.

Comment: Jon is correct I remember doing this exactly in sql server.. to short circuit my where clause based on parameter.. I need to try this to see if it gets me my result.

Comment: This solution is what I was looking for but thanks for that Note Jon. I don't want to write something that I did in sql. I want to write cleaner and efficient code.. but this is a good example/solution that I may revisit if need be.